# An align environment question

Tags: spacing, align

Currently i have something like this:

```
  \[ A = B \]
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
  AAA = BBBB &=  CCCCCCCC  &&= DDDD \\
  AAA = BBBB &=  \qquad CCC  &&= DDDD \\
  \end{alignat*}
```

In would like to have almost the same effect without the vertical spacing between the first and second equation, so is there a way to push first equation inside the aligned environment and keeping it centered?

Also, is there a better way to center the "CCC" in the third equation?

Comment: The spacing above and below of those environments is controlled by the lengths `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`. Use a group around your math stuff and set the lengths to appropiate values then. For the centering I have no clue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Just `amsmath`

You can use `alignedat` inside a `gather*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
 A = B \\
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
  AAA = BBBB &=  CCCCCCCC  &&= DDDD \\
  AAA = BBBB &=  \qquad CCC  &&= DDDD \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

### Centering using the `calc` package

One possible way of centering `CCC` is to use `\widthof` from the `calc` package to calculate the width of `CCCCCCCC`, and set `CCC` centered in a box of this width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
 A = B \\
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
  AAA = BBBB &=  CCCCCCCC  &&= DDDD \\
  AAA = BBBB &=   \makebox[\widthof{$\displaystyle CCCCCCCC$}][c]{$\displaystyle CCC$}  &&= DDDD \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### A variant of Ignasi's answer

Here I add the equals sign to the array specification instead of typing them explicitly. To get the better spacing an empty group is added on either side, i.e. `@{ {}={} }`.

`\jot` is the default spacing between lines in multiline math environments from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{*{3}{@{} c@{ {}={} }} c}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{A=B}\\[\jot]
AAA  & BBBB  & CCCCCCCC  & DDDD \\[\jot]
AAA  & BBBB  & CCC  & DDDD \\[\jot]
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: use `array`. Intercolumn space is not nice, but it can be adjusted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{*{7}{c}}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\begin{array}{ccc}A&=&B\end{array}}\\
AAA & = & BBBB & = & CCCCCCCC  &=& DDDD \\
AAA & = & BBBB &=  & CCC  &= &DDDD \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Still not perfect, but next code looks nicer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{array}{*{4}{c}}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{A=B}\\
AAA  = & BBBB  = & CCCCCCCC  &= DDDD \\
AAA  = & BBBB =  & CCC  &= DDDD \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]